# PHP mail() doesn't work in digitalocean ubuntu 18

Tags: php, email, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04

I tried this guide here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-mail-function-enable

but nothing seems to work.

mail doesn't send any error and it mail function returns TRUE however, i didn't receive any email in gmail.

```
$to      = 'myexampleemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
   echo 'error';
```

*where myexampleemail@gmail.com is my email of course.*
*doesn't echo 'error' so it means it was success?*

any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Use libraries like PHPMailer.

Comment: Turns out digital ocean is blocking the port by default.